# System of three equations, one term squared

Tags: statistics

Find the unknowns, given that $E(X) = 1$ and $V(X) = 22.9375$

[image]

I have

$8a+8c=3$

$-5a+\frac{9b}{32} +4c +1.75 = 1$

and $25a+ \frac{9b^2}{32} +16c +14 = \frac{367}{16}$

which I can form a quadratic in terms of $b$ only (or any other variable)

However, I think the equations are not right because the answers I get are not correct.

I feel maybe difficulties arise because of the $b^2$; it is thus not a system of LINEAR equations and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: V(X) means variance Var(X). Isn't $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ ie $\sum{p(x)x^2} - 1$? So it does have to do with p(x). What is f(x) you are talking about?

Comment: Okay I got it. $V(X)$ means variance of random variable in the probability distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two equation you got, are correct.In the third equation you forgot to subtract 1 from the LHS, as you yourself pointed out $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2= \sum{ x^2 p(x)} -1$. Using first and second equation, first eliminate $c$ to get a relation between $a$ and $b$. You'll get $$9a- \frac{9b}{32}= 2.25$$  Write $a$ in terms of $b$, i.e. $a=0.25+\frac{b}{32}$. Now substitute this value of $a$ in the first equation to get $c$ in terms of $b$, i.e $c=0.125-\frac{b}{32}$.

Substitute these values of $a$ and $c$ in the third equation $$ (25a+ \frac{9b^2}{32} +16c +14)-1 = \frac{367}{16}$$
to get a quadratic equation in b. You'll get $$ 6.25+\frac{25b}{32} +\frac{9b^2}{32}+2-\frac{16b}{32}+14-1-22.9375=0$$

$$\implies \frac{9b^2}{32} + \frac{9b}{32}-1.6875=0$$
$$\implies 9b^2+9b-54=0 \implies b^2+b-6=0 \implies (b+3)(b-2)=0$$
$\therefore b=-3$ or $2$

The possible set of values for $a,b,c$ are $\{a=0.15625,b=-3,c=0.21875\}, \{a=0.3125,b=2,c=0.0625\}$

Comment: My answers say that b = -3 or b = 2 which isnt a solution of the quadratic.

Comment: You are right. I can't believe I forgot to minus that one. Do you have any tips to eliminate this type of silly mistake in the future? I did the question on a separate piece of paper and managed to forget the one twice!

Comment: @user71207 Tips to eliminate this type of silly mistake!! :) Didn't you see I myself forgot that minus 1 and jumped to an incorrect quadratic equation at first and that too after we discussed $(\sum{x p(x)})^2=1$ in the comments. I can't help myself with mistakes like these, what tips can I share with you!

Comment: I see, but you did indeed spot the mistake quicker than I did!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to solve the problem is to realize that

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{V}(X)+\mathbb{E}^2(X)$$

and $c=1-0.625-a$

thus setting the following system

$$\begin{cases}
-5a+0.28125b+4\cdot(0.375-a)+1.75=1\\
25a+0.28125b^2+16\cdot(0.375-a)+14=22.9375+1
\end{cases}$$

Expanding...

$$\begin{cases}
-9a+0.28125b+1.5+1.75=1\\
9a+0.28125b^2+6+14=23.9375
\end{cases}$$

Now simply summing member by member you get new equation

$$0.28125\cdot b(1+b)=1.6875$$

giving the two requested solutions for $b=\{2;-3\}$

---

EDIT: further explanation answering to your comments

Simple [moments](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-moments-in-statistics-3126234) (for a discrete rv) are defined by

$$\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\Sigma_i X_i^k\cdot p(x_i)$$

It is well known (and easy to prove that) the variance can be expressed by

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

or equivalently

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\mathbb{V}[X]+\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

Now you are given a rv with mean=1 (first moment) and variance=22.9375 that is second moment $E(X^2)=23.9375$

It is natural for me set a two-equation's system in the following form:

$$\begin{cases}
x_1\cdot p(x_1)+x_2\cdot p(x_2)+\dots+x_n\cdot p(x_n)=1 \\
x_1^2\cdot p(x_1)+x_2^2\cdot p(x_2)+\dots+x_n^2\cdot p(x_n)=23.9375
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am all ears for a quicker solution. How does $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{V}(X)+\mathbb{E}^2(X)$ speed things up?

Comment: @user71207: this, together with setting $c$ as a function of $a$, if you look at my system of equations, it self simplifies, obtaining in one passage a simple quadratic equation. I think it is faster...anyway it is another solution

Comment: i see. did you notice this the first attempt, or after working out the question wholly?

Comment: @user71207: Yes, I used the most natural way to proceed in these case. The important thing is that you now got the right solution. Variance can always be exprssed in terms of moments, and often this is the fastest way to solve problems. Moreover you have a $0$ term in your support, and working with moments this term self cancels

Comment: What do you mean "you have a $0$ term in your support"? I suspect it has something to do with the $-9a + 9a$ cancellation?

Comment: @user71207 the support of your rv is $X=\{-5;b;0;4;8\}$. The value zero when calculating moments self cancels, thus I think it is better to work on moments and not on mean and variance. That's all..then setting the system in this way immediately you realize that $a$ and $c$ parameters self simplify...but it is only my opinion...you can solve the problem in a lot of different ways

Comment: No, I think your method is the best that I have seen so far. I am not trained in statistics so could you please explain what a moment is? Wikipedia says it relates to the shape of the function's graph, and that variance and mean are moments?. So does working in moments mean not using the variance and mean given?

Comment: @user71207: I added some edits in my answer. I hope now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

If $V(X)=23.9375$, the solutions are $b=-3$, and $b=2$.

Comment: I believe the variance is not wrong. I made a mistake of ignoring the minus one in the final equation

Comment: @giuseppe mancò: the variance is correcly 22.9375. The second moment is 23.9375 (immota manet)